# Should I split this question into two?

Tags: support, specific-question

Should I split my question ([Is it almost impossible to find animals that are not contaminated by chemicals?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/is-it-almost-impossible-to-find-animals-that-are-not-contaminated-by-chemicals)) into two separate questions? I will need one answer moved and perhaps another split into two if so.

Please advise.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

Usually you shouldn't edit a question after it's been answered, if the edit would invalidate existing answers.

Here you have two closely-related questions in one topic: that's OK because the questions are closely-related (and they're both questioning the same source i.e. Carson if not quite the same claim).

And two answers, both on-topic because they're both addressing (different parts of) the question.